# Github Shared as Link in visual studio

Tags: github

Hi I have a git repository which is linked to my solution in visual studio

I have added some code to my solution that is outside of my repository as the code is shared across multiple solutions. I have added the code as add existing item add as Link.

How do I go about adding this code to git. It needs to be shared across multiple projects hence the reason for adding as a link.

Answer (score 1):

If your using a setup that is basically 1 git repository per solution then I see 2 real options.  Unless you want to refactor things and make a separate solution for those shared components and then consume it as a nuget package.

1. Include the shared code in an existing repository and force a specific directory structure for the checked out repositories.

**Update : a bit more information** This would force you to make a decision about where that shared code lives.  In your Team city configuration you would have to check out the repository with the shared code along with the solution you are trying to build.  It would force your build and development environments to maintain repositories side-by-side.

2. Create a new repository for the shared components and add that repository as a [git submodule](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

**Personally, I would go this route**

**Update : a bit more information**This creates a parent to child relationship.  If the shared code is in a repository x when you checkout your solutions repo, the x repository will be inside of it and also checked out.  I don't really know much about team city, but I believe you can have it pull down the submodule's along with the repository. It shouldn't affect your CI environment.

Each comes with their own unique set of challenges.  Depending on your exact goals I can't really give anymore information.

Comment: I have this under ci in team city will the check out on a git subtree pull latest from a shared location

Comment: if you could give me a bit more details on these two options would be great

Comment: user1853454 I added a tiny bit more information.  The options are pretty simple.  The second one is probably easier to use with TeamCity